# Preventing an interface from being implemented in an other assembly

Tags: c#

I have the following in assembly C :

```
public interface InterfaceA
{
    string Data {get; }
}

public interface InterfaceB
{
    InterfaceA DoStuff();

}

public interface InterfaceC
{
    IEnumerable<InterfaceA> GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone();
}
```

An implementation of InterfaceB is, called Doer is defined in the Assembly A (which is the main project).
Similarly an implementation of the InterfaceA is defined in AssemblyA, but the assembly B knows nothing about these implementations.

The assembly B will be developped by an external company, and will be referenced by assembly A (not dynamically, at design time). The purpose of this company is to write an implementation for InterfaceC.

Here is the situation : I want to prevent the external company from creating its own implementation of InterfaceA and putting it in the list they return in InterfaceC.GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone(). The intended usage is : they call InterfaceB.DoStuff(), get an instance of InterfaceA, and add it to the list that they will return.

I have to make an assumption on the type of the objects contained in the list returned by InterfaceC.GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone(). I know they will all have a certain type that is only defined in assembly A. Therefore I'm trying to make sure that these objects will only be created in assembly A, and I want to enforce this at compile time to avoid discovering MyCustomImplementionOfA objects in the list.

Therefore I'm trying to figure out how to prevent an interface from being implemented in another assembly. I'm thinking that perhaps there can be a way around it by slightly rethinking my design buy I don't seem to find one.

Thank you

Comment: Thats ver strange request. Why do you want that?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: @TcKs Basically, to leverage the interface segregation principle. I want the persons implementing assembly B to only use the data that matters for them. They modify the domain entities through abstractions encapsulated by these interfaces. But from the perspective of Assembly A, I want to be using these domain entities. Interfaces B and C encapsulate services and "DTO" if you want, interfaceA encapsulates a domain object. I want to make sure, my domain objects are returned in InterfaceC

Comment: Why do you need them all to be of a particular type?

Comment: But it doesn't mean, you can not implement that in another assembly. You try solve some architectonic rule by typing system. It's not good idea. And this one rule is not possible wire into type constraints.

Comment: You are searching a technical solution for a communication problem. Talking to the people which will implement your proposal sounds mich more efficient to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this is to create an opaque object which you pass back to them:

```
internal interface InterfaceA
{
    string Data {get; }
}
public interface InterfaceB
{
    OpaqueToken DoStuff();
}

public interface InterfaceC
{
    IEnumerable<OpaqueToken> GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone();
}

public sealed class OpaqueToken
{
    internal OpaqueToken() {} 
    internal InterfaceA A { get; set; }
}
```

This way `InterfaceA` is internal, so only code within your library (unless you use `InternalsVisibleTo`) will be able to implement it. The consumer of your library will only see instances of `OpaqueToken` and your constructor is internal so they won't be able to invoke it. The object which implements `InterfaceA` will only be accessible within your library as well. `OpaqueToken` could even implement `InterfaceA` if you like.

It's important to point out that this is not a security measure -- any consumer using reflection can violate all these rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik, this is exactly the design approach I was after. I have accepted the answer of alexm as I like the formulation with an abstract and it is the one I'll go with, but you're really the one who got the right approach and unlocked the whole thing. Thank you so much for that.

Thanks, of course this is not for security it is mainly to make the code self-documenting, and take advantage of compile time checks. Then at some point, I need to trust the third party anyway as you outlined, but very nice design thank you, couldn't find it

Answer (score 5):

I like the solution with the opaque token proposed by Eric. 
You can also pull this trick by using an *abstract class* in place of your `InterfaceA` and making its constructor internal.

```
public abstract class ContractA
{
   internal ContractA() {};
   public abstract string Data {get; }

}
```

Comment: That seem to be it. Constructor internal, and InternalsVisibleTo( AssemblyA), to make sure that only the assembly A can instantiate it

Answer (score -1):

Mark the interface as [internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx), then if you need to reference the interface from any of your own assemblies (e.g. not the one it's defined in), you can use [internalsvisibleto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to specify which assemblies can "see" it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is the Assembly B needs to know about this interface, otherwise it can't create the list :/

Comment: Use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`

Comment: I get that it's being developed by an external company, but so long as you know the name of the assembly you should be able to provide the means for them to reference the interface.

Comment: Yes but then, the external company can create a custom implementation for this interface and put an object having the custom type in the list they return to me. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Ah yes, I see your conundrum, and you can't even move `InterfaceA` into a separate assembly either, as `InterfaceC` references it. In this instance then I'd say no, there's no way of preventing this.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too :/ thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you have to move it to a separate assembly? Internal states you cannot inherit in a second assembly. No matter if both public and internal interface are declared in the same assembly.

Comment: @S22 not true, if you use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` then you can indeed inherit / implement an internal type from a different assembly.

Comment: Sure, but if you have access to code, you could more simply change internal to public. What is your point? If it is possible to alter this in a sign assembly it is a major flaw by MS.

Comment: @S22 but the third party company don't have access to the code... So this allows the OP to do what they want.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a hint of what you can do:

```
public interface InterfaceA
{
    // Only expose what is of public interest!
    string Description { get; }
}

internal interface InterfaceAInternal : InterfaceA
{
    string Data { get; }
}

public interface InterfaceB
{
    InterfaceA DoStuff();
}

internal interface InterfaceC
{
    IEnumerable<InterfaceAInternal> GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone();
}

public interface InterfaceD
{
    IEnumerable<InterfaceA> GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone();
}
```

and don't take notice on juharr's naive comments below. She might have a good reputation, but it is not based on true knowledge / competence of programming.

Comment: If you don't fully understand the question why are you giving an answer?

Comment: I do my best, even if the question is not clear.I think this is what you need. You cannot possible have considered my answer in the short time after my post

Comment: I did and it won't work because `InterfaceA` is still `public` and the 3rd party could still implement it.  Not to mention that `InterfaceC` has to be `public` as that is the interface the OP does want the 3rd party implementing.

Comment: How is it limited?  And before you call someone stupid you should stop and think "Maybe I don't know what I'm talking about".

Comment: Ok, sorry, my bad manner. InterfaceA is the public interface, which you let the whole world implement, then you haver you're secret internal interface winch you expects in your internal code, unless this secret interface is implemented you simply throw an exception. InterfaceA is still implemented no matter what.

Comment: But the problem is that `InterfaceC` is `internal`, how will the 3rd party implement it?  And once you  make that `public` you have to make `InterfaceAInternal` `public` too and you're just back to the same problem.

Comment: Ok, The internal interface is never to be implemented by external party. Maybe I missed something here? The external party is left with the public "restricted" interface. When external company sends a InterfaceA, it is really an interfaceA and not a interfaceAInternal. Your receiving code will determine this and treat it different. It MIGHT not be the exact answer you're looking for, but a possible solution.

Comment: And when it comes to interfaceC, if this has to be public, you simply let it be as you declared it:
public interface InterfaceC
{
IEnumerable<InterfaceA> GetStuffThatHaveBeenDone();
}
InterfaceAInternal is strictly internal!